# Undefined index error on options array element?

Tags: errors, wp-debug

WP_DEBUG is telling me:

> Notice: Undefined index: no_cat_base
>   in myplugin.php on line 20

Here's the lines of code where I'm pulling the value of "no_cat_base" from my options array called "myoptions"...

```
$myoptions = get_option('my_settings');

if($myoptions['no_cat_base']){//This is line 20}
```

Is the correct fix for this...

```
if ( isset($myoptions['no_cat_base'])){//do something}
```

Comment: Not 100% sure, but if you're expecting an array from your setting (i.e. you're pulling `action_plugins` setting from the database), I believe you have to cast it as an array?

Comment: Yes, its a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to be on the safe side use:

```
if (array_key_exists('no_cat_base', $myoptions) && isset($myoptions['no_cat_base'])){
//do your thing
}
```

Comment: isset is enough, no need for array_key_exists

Comment: As i posted "just to be on the safe side", but yes isset is enough